# In Hyperledger Fabric, how can a peer on, for example, on channel1 access the ledger of channel2?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have isolated two organizations into two different channels. Organizations one and two are part of channel1, and organizations three and four are part of channel two. I would like to ask if it is possible that one peer on channel2 access queries the ledger of channel1 and vice-versa. If it is possible how can I do it?

I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe with an HTTP adapter on the top of your peers?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in your current setup because the peers who have joined the channel can only access that channel. Peers that are not part of the channel can not access the ledger data.

What you can do is, bring the peers on the common channel and can use PDC (Private Data Collection) to make the transaction private to the organization/Organizations.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric is a private and permissioned blockchain.

A channel is a private blockchain overlay which allows for data isolation and confidentiality. A channel-specific ledger is shared across the peers in the channel, and transacting parties must be authenticated to a channel in order to interact with it. Channels are defined by a Configuration-Block.

At channel creation time, all organizations added to the channel must be part of a consortium. However, an organization that is not defined in a consortium may be added to an existing channel like by adding an new organization into that channel with fulfilling endorsement policy.

So to be a part of a channel, your organizational peer must need access according to the consortium. A peer can be a part of multiple channel and the ledger/database of every peer within a channel is identical/same, to invoke/query the ledger we need smart contact which is also identical among every peer of that channel. So if my peer server is a part of two channel, I need two ledgers/databases. To access the data of a ledger for invoke/query, you need corresponding smart contract.

According to your current setup, it's not possible and this is the nature of private-permissioned blockchain and to make it possible, you have to change the consortium with appropriate endorcement.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to make peer on **channel2** to access ledger of **channel1** is to join the peer into channel1. Otherwise it is not possible to access the data.